# javascript popup in Timer control and UpdatePanel control not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, timer, updatepanel

MasterPage.master

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000">
    </asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

MasterPage.master.vb

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    'some sql select codes

    con.Open()
    Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32) 'ExecuteScalar() only return 1 row and ignore rest
    con.Close()

    If result > 0 Then

        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('hello world');", True)
        'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('" & result & " hello world');", True)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel1, Me.UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert(‘hello world’);", True)


    End If

End Sub
```

Basically I have a `Timer` control that run a SQL Select on a fixed interval and if the `result` is greater than 0, there will be a popup alert.

The codes work fine if I do not use an `UpdatePanel` but without the `UpdatePanel`, whenever the `Timer` control runs, the page will refresh, causing whatever the user is working on to be lost.

edit: further clarification

`Timer1_Tick` does run every 10sec. The problem lies with the pop-up, no pop-up occurs on the browser.

Comment: Dont use UpdatePanel. Use jquery ajax with javascript settimout page will not refresh the page...

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnTick="Timer1_Tick"` to your `.master` markup.

Also, you should not need to, but your could try adding:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: tried changing to `<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000"  OnTick="Timer1_Tick">` but it still didn't work.

Comment: @j_t_fusion I have added more to my answer. Can you try adding the triggers?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. In my original code, `Timer1_Tick` does run every 10sec, the problem is that no pop-up on the browser occurs.